# How can I get the result with underscore.js filter?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Here is the test array:

```
var test = [
{
    "id": 1, 
    "team": [
        {
            "name": "Alex", 
            "age": 27, 
            "checked": true
        }, 
        {
            "name": "Bob", 
            "age": 35,
            "checked": false
        }
    ], 
    "checked": true
}, 
{
    "id": "2", 
    "team": [
        {
            "name": "Jack", 
            "age": 37, 
            "checked": false
        }, 
        {
            "name": "Tom", 
            "age": 29, 
            "checked": true
        }
    ], 
    "checked": true
}];
```

And the result that I want to get is an array like this:

result = ["Alex", "Tom"];

The result array contains all items that the "checked" attribute equals to true in team.
I try to get the result with the underscore.js [filter](http://underscorejs.org/#filter), but I cannot get the correct result. 
If you have a better solution, please tell me.
Here is my code:

```
_.filter(test, function(team) {
 _.filter(team, function(worker){
    if(worker.checked)
        return worker.name;
 });});
```

Comment: Please post your code so we can help you.

Comment: Add the actual filter code....

Comment: Thanks. My code updated.

Comment: What you have implemented will not work because _.filter expects a function which returns true or false (predicate) and not a string value. Js will interpret the string as true and the code will still run. There is no way to achieve what you want only with _.filter. If you really want a underscore only solution, go with _.each.

Comment: @mrak nonsense, these libraries are a tad bit more robust than you tell. You almost never just use one function standalone from these libraries, but rather combine for powerful data manipulation and extraction. See the other answers below for proper examples.

Comment: @Plantface Would you mind to explain what is nonsense about my comment? I just pointed out 1) why OPs _.filter is not working for this example and 2) why OP used wrong arguments for this function anyway. I just suggested to use _.each which is exactly the same as suggested answer with forEach. forEach is not supported by e.x. IE8 and for that case its better to go with underscores _.each.

Comment: @mrak "If you really want a underscore only solution, go with _.each." This is nonsense as contrary to what you say, it can be solved with _.filter, combined with the other API. Doing a manual _.each is not needed. I agree nonsense was a bit strong. My apology.

Comment: @Plantface My comment on _.filter was only related to what OP has posted (nesting _.filter). Valid point: it sounds to general. Btw very nice and more readable one line solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use [`forEach` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to handle this

```
var test = [...];

var result = [];

test.forEach(function(item) {
    item.team.forEach(function(worker) {
        if(worker.checked) {
            result.push(worker.name);
        }
    })
})

console.log(result)
//Return ["Alex","Tom"]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I just make things harder than necessary.

Comment: You can use plain javascript for everything. How to make code readable, reusable and expressive is the hard part. Don't reinvent the wheel. `var result = _.chain(test).pluck('team').flatten().filter({checked:true}).value();`

Answer (score 4):

Here's how you can do it in both underscore and [lodash](https://lodash.com/):

[Underscore jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wr20zz9r/):

```
var result = _.chain(test).pluck('team').flatten().filter({checked:true}).value();
```

[Lodash jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ae4hp58v/):

```
var result = _(test).pluck('team').flatten().filter({checked:true}).value();
```

Take the team arrays together, flatten them so you have the nested arrays, filter on the property and the result are the objects containing the name and checked being true. If you want just the names, do another pluck.

Here's an underscorejs version with a [shorter filter and just giving back the names](https://jsfiddle.net/wr20zz9r/1/):

```
var result = _.chain(test).pluck('team').flatten().filter('checked').pluck('name').value();
// ["Alex", "Tom"]
```

Comment: Beautiful. Didn't know that underscore allowed a property name in filter (and many other functions) and wrapped it in a _.property call.

Answer (score -1):

One way to use filtering for multidimentional array is by using `filter` and `any`.

```
_.filter(test, function(team) {
    return _.any(team.team, function(player) {
        return player.checked;
    });
});
```

Comment: this returns the entire test array